# Gson - questions about versioning

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am looking at the [Versioning Support section](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Versioning-Support) of the Gson User Guide.

Question 1: It says you can use the @Since annotation on Classes, Fields, and (in a future release) Methods.  I understand serialization of an object's fields, but what does it mean to serialize a *class* and a *method*?

Question 2: It says that when you create your Gson object, you can specify a version, and then any field annotated with @Since and a version number greater than that will be ignored.  What exactly is the point of this?  I know that when the Json contains extra fields that do not exist in the Java class to which it is being deserialized, then those fields are ignored.  So why would you ever need to use the @Since annotation?

Comment: For Que 2. What if the value datatype changes, thats why its different than json parsing. Example for this is shared here . http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/json/google-gson/versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

For Question 2:
@Since helps you for serialization mainly. The fields with version number greater will be ignored, therefore you write a JSON for a previous version from the current newer classes.

@Since has influences also on deserealization, not so useful in my opinion. Using @Since for deserealization will ignore some of the fields present in JSON and also present in classes, if version number used is less that those some fields. Not that useful in my opinion because you read a new version JSON in a new class like reading an old version JSON in the new class.

JSON Example:

```
{
    oldField: "value1",
    newField: "value2"
}
```

Java class:

```
class MyClass {
    @Since(0.0)
    public String oldField;
    @Since(1.0)
    public String newField;
}
```

Java Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setVersion(0.0).create();
    MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson("{oldField: \"value1\", newerField: \"value2\"}", MyClass.class);

    System.out.println("read as version 0.0:");
    System.out.println(myClass.oldField);
    System.out.println(myClass.newField);


    Gson gson2 = new GsonBuilder().create();
    MyClass myClass2 =  gson2.fromJson("{oldField: \"value1\", newField: \"value2\"}", MyClass.class);

    System.out.println("read without version specified:");
    System.out.println(myClass2.oldField);
    System.out.println(myClass2.newField);
}
```

Result showing how newField was ignored if @Since is smaller:

```
read as version 0.0
value1
null

read without version specified
value1
value2
```